# CAGR Calculation for different variables in R

Tags: r, function

I was inspired by these 2 photos. First I wanted to get a single value for each  So I grouped them together and averaged them for each year.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor

growth <- function(x, y){
  ((x / first(x)) ^ (1 / (y - first(y)))) - 1
}

data_df <- tribble(
  ~Crop, ~Year, ~Area, ~Yield, ~Rainfall,
  "Coconut ", 2000L, 18168, 3583.22324966975, 2763.2,
  "Coconut ", 2001L, 18190, 3542.05607476636, 3080.9,
  "Coconut ", 2002L, 18240, 3700.10964912281, 2620.2,
  "Coconut ", 2003L, 18284.74, 3750.66859031083, 2355.9,
  "Coconut ", 2004L, 18394.7, 2847.5593513349, 2460.1,
  "Coconut ", 2005L, 13876.57, 3749.48564378661, 2954.7,
  "Coconut ", 2006L, 14358, 4134.97701629753, 2404.7,
  "Rice", 2000L, 102, 3.14705882352941, 2763.2,
  "Rice", 2001L, 83, 3.6144578313253, 3080.9,
  "Rice", 2002L, 189.2, 2.7, 2620.2,
  "Rice", 2003L, 52, 1.73403846153846, 2355.9,
  "Rice", 2004L, 52.94, 1.37079712882508, 2460.1,
  "Rice", 2005L, 2.09, 5.77033492822967, 2954.7,
  "Rice", 2006L, 6854.3, 2.77134353617437, 2404.7,
  "Sugarcane", 2000L, 1, 2, 2763.2,
  "Sugarcane", 2001L, 1, 1, 3080.9,
  "Sugarcane", 2002L, 5, 8, 2620.2,
  "Sugarcane", 2003L, 268, 10.7444776119403, 2355.9,
  "Sugarcane", 2006L, 0.2, 2.5, 2404.7
) 

data_df |> 
  group_by(Crop) |> 
  mutate(across(c(Area, Rainfall, Yield), ~ growth(., Year), .names = "{.col}_cagr")) |> 
  slice_tail(n = 1) |> 
  pivot_longer(ends_with("_cagr")) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Crop, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_percent()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "CAGR", fill = NULL) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello again, I think there is a mistake, but I don't know if I explained my purpose correctly. I edited the question and added a plot. At the end I'm trying to make a graph like this. So I only need to get 1 CAGR for each crop and for area, yield, rainfall. How can we find a solution to this to get a graph similar to the graph above?

Comment: Updated to take the CAGR for the final year and plot

Comment: At that time I was trying in my own way. But I couldn't continue. I've edited the question again, can you help me check and continue?

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: @Emily I'm a bit unclear now as to what you're asking. The plot above gives you one CAGR (based on the first and last years) for each Crop/Area, each Crop/Yield and each Crop/Rainfall.  Your sample data has two rows for each Crop/Year with some years missing; is that intended?

Comment: Okay, I understand, your code gives what i exactly want. Thank you, but  I need to add the growth.rate function that I wrote at the beginning. It gave same answer like yours. But how can add this function to your code, instead of ((. / first(.)) ^ (1 / (Year - first(Year)))) - 1

Comment: I've separated out the `growth` function.